# Is it good practice to use a object literal as a hash table?

Tags: javascript, hash, hashtable

Is it good practice to use a object literal as a hash table? i.e use a property name as the key to get a particular mapped value back.

For example:

```
var colorArray = [
    { code: "#4286f4", name: "Blue" }, 
    { code: "#fc4d02", name: "Red" }
]

var hashTable = {}

colorArray.forEach(color => {
  hashTable[color.code] = color.name
})
```

Is this an acceptable use for object literals, or is there a pattern out there that will better handle a hash map in JavaScript?

Comment: I would argue that this is more of a code review question and not a issue for stack overflow.

Comment: No such thing as  JSON object. JSON is a text data format. But using object literals as hashmap is common practice

Comment: Note that using objects as a hashmap is a totally legit pattern, but if you can use es6, then the built in `Map` type is also available.

Comment: yes, and it's serialize-able and very fast that way, unlike Maps. there's a few implicit properties you need to watch out for "toString", "hasOwnProperty", etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before ES6 using a literal object was the only way to have a hashmap in JS. Since ES6, you can also use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const colorArray = [{code: "#4286f4" , name: "Blue"}, {code: "#fc4d02", name: "Red"}];

const map = new Map(colorArray.map(({ code, name }) => [code, name]));

console.log(map); // look at the browser's console

console.log(map.get("#4286f4"));
```

Comment: Didn't know about his change in ES6. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.